# How I could clean UINavigationBar transitions history?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I currently have parental "menu" `TableView` with `UINavigationBar` and from each `cell` there is a segues by `reference outlet` to 3 similar `Views` with different information.

In each `View` there is a `buttons` to other 2 `Views`.

With every `button`'s segue opens another `View`.

The problem:
From every `View` `UINavigationBar`'s `back button` returns me to previous `View` but i tries to make `back button` to "menu".

Additional `Bar Button Item` and segue from it makes very close effect but segue animation is not like in `UINavigationController`.

How I could clean UINavigationBar transitions history in segue to initial View?

Comment: I think you’re looking for pop to root view controller (animated:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try pop to root view controller or You can edit navigation controller `viewControllers` property and remove/add some VC in between.

You can try Unwind Segue mechanism too.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some methods(function) that navigation controller providing for pop operations. They are returning optional UIViewController (intance) from it’s navigation stack, that is popped.

```
open func popViewController(animated: Bool) -> UIViewController? // Returns the popped controller.

open func popToViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) -> [UIViewController]? // Pops view controllers until the one specified is on top. Returns the popped controllers.

open func popToRootViewController(animated: Bool) -> [UIViewController]?
```

Here is sample code as a solution to your query::

```
// if you want to back to root of your app
if let rootNavigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
     rootNavigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}

// But if you want to back to root of your current navigation 
if let viewcontroller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewViewController") as? NewViewController { // or instantiate view controller using any other method
     viewcontroller.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```